# How is the "Security" of a PDF established by Ubuntu/Gnome?

Tags: gnome, encryption, pdf

The PDF document properties (Via GUI) shows a pdf's "Security" as below.

[image: Gnome pdf document info]

Running the pdf through qpdf with the command:

```
qpdf in.pdf --encrypt "" "" 40 --print=n --modify=n -- out.pdf
```

Gives the same result in GUI but pdfinfo gives:

[image: pdfinfo output of pdf]

This holds true for 128-bit and 256-bit AES.

What does the "Security" label mean?